# How can I find the radius and interval of convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n(x^{n+1}) \over \sqrt{n}+3} $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty {(-1)^n(x^{n+1}) \over \sqrt{n}+3} $$

I think I'm supposed to take the absolute value of the sum and apply the ratio test, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Do exactly that and then comment if you get stuck.

Comment: @Rod Already was stuck, wanted to make sure I started correctly. I have x[(sqrtn)+3] over [sqrt(n+1) + 3]

Comment: Below should be more than enough to get you started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_n \frac{x^{n+1}\cdot x}{\sqrt{n+1}+3} \cdot \frac{\sqrt{n}+3}{x^{n+1}} = |x|\lim_n \frac{\sqrt{n}+3}{\sqrt{n+1}+3}=|x| \lim_n \frac{\frac{\sqrt{n}}{\sqrt{n+1}}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n+1}}}{1+\frac{3}{\sqrt{n+1}}} = |x|$$

Comment: I guess I just don't see how to simplify that. I'm gonna say it's equal to just |x|

Comment: Do that make sense? Now what is interval of convergence and radius of convergence?

Comment: That makes sense, but one question, why again can you use sqrt(n+1) as the denominator for everything

Comment: Interval of convergence would be -1<|x|<1, radius would be 1

Comment: Yes, that is correct. Well partially. You now have to check the endpoints.

Comment: Like plugging in -1 and 1 for x into the original sum?

Comment: Yes. When you plug $\pm1$ to the original sum, apply Alternating Series Test to get you're result.

Comment: You're a gentleman and a scholar